# shadowDom Яндекс.карты проблема совместимости

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, polymer

Не важно какую версию скрипта я использую  отрабатывает не корректно в связке c ShadowDom, в дебаг режиме выдается ошибка "Uncaught Error: util.dom.element.html: попытка переопределить innerHTML у элемента, не добавленного в документ"
пример где можно увидеть проблему 
https://jsfiddle.net/haor7c9u/12/ ,а в минифицированном скрипте не удается использовать экземпляр карты, например так

`var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.8, 37.6]);
 map.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);`

т.е. карта отрисовывается, но не добавить элемент управления, не добавить метки на карту нет возможности.

Answer (score 1):

Поддержки Shadow DOM сейчас нет.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/280452)

Comment: @Sublihim, API Яндекс.Карт не поддерживает Shadow DOM в последней на сегодняшний день версии 2.1.68 (17 июля 2018).