# Не загружаются тайлы Яндекс Карт из за CORS

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

столкнулся со следующей проблемой, делаю приложение на Vue.js, в процессе разработки на локалке все работает в штатном режиме, однако, после сборки приложения в веб-компонент и интеграции этого веб-компонента в приложение на ангуляре, запросы на получение тайлов формата `https://core-renderer-tiles.maps.yandex.net/tiles?` получают статус `canceled` и карта соответственно не прорисовывается, выглядит ошибка так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в payload запроса есть подозрительные NaN, но я не знаю как их фиксить и из-за чего они посылаются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же стоит заметить, что сам скрипт ymaps3 загружается успешно со статусом 200
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А также стоит заметить, что приложение, которое встраивается в ангуляр как web-component в итоге работает внутри shadow-dom'а, я нашел этот тред[shadowDom Яндекс.карты проблема совместимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862303/shadowdom-%D0%AF%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) и хочу уточнить, актуальна ли эта проблема на данный момент? Работают ли яндекс карты внутри shadow dom'a?